# How to check if "Count equals 50 then"?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Edited question totally for more understanding.

I have a count function, and I have a label who checks the current count

Here is the label

```
        private void currentCountLabel_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

How do I make so once the label reaches as example 50, a function starts. like play sound?

//////////////////////////////

Here is the current one that @btc sources, gave me

```
        private void currentCountLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.Compare(currentCountLabel.Text, "5") == 0)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"sound.wav");
            player.Play();
        }     
    }
```

But it wont play automaticly, how do I make it to play when it reaches the number?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
        private void currentCountLabel_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.Compare(currentCountLabel.Text, "5") == 0)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"meme.wav");
            player.Play();
        }     
    }

        private void writeToFile()
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.OBSToggle)
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.ReverseOrder)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"Count.txt", String.Format("{0} {1}", Count.ToString(), Message));

            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"Count.txt", String.Format("{0} {1}", Message, Count.ToString()));
            }
        }

 private void KeyBoardHook_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.HotKeyEnabled && e.KeyCode == Properties.Settings.Default.HotKeyIn)
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.SaveCount)
            {
                Count = Count + 1;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Count = Count;
                currentCountLabel.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Count.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Count = Count + 1;
                currentCountLabel.Text = Count.ToString();
            }
            Message = messageTextBox.Text;
            writeToFile();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.HotKeyEnabled && e.KeyCode == Properties.Settings.Default.HotKeyDe && Count != 0)
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.SaveCount)
            {
                Count = Count - 1;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Count = Count;
                currentCountLabel.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Count.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Count = Count - 1;
                currentCountLabel.Text = Count.ToString();
            }
            Message = messageTextBox.Text;
            writeToFile();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking on how to use an `if` statement?

Comment: I see no relationship between the code you've posted and your question (and neither your code nor your question makes any sense). Could you please ask a coherent question?

Comment: I honestly don't know what to make, Pretty sure its not an "if" I should use, unless its on a  other side of the code. It should probably be in the same function as the previous if, but I don't know the code to make it check for the current "count number". I want it to be able to do something once you get the count number at 50, or 100 ect.

Comment: @JLRishe I want a function that should be able to see from the count.txt and once the number reaches 50, it does something else

Comment: @Heinzi   I edited the main question post

Comment: Updated the answer too. As I said before, use `TextChanged` event instead of `Click` to auto play the sound.

Comment: Well, the question now is different to the original one, so you should start a new question. This one is spoiling since the topic has change. I'll look for it when you start it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need a static variable to hold the current count. Initialized to zero.  Then increment it each time the function executes.

Then an if statement to evaluate the count and take whatever action.

Comment: I do have this to hold 0 each time program starts if thats what you are asking?

  this.currentCountLabel.Text = "0";

Comment: There's no need to use a static var, but a global one, since he needs to update the value from the count function, which is not executed on the label click.